# One Table to Multiple Table Mapping using Hibernate Annotation

Tags: hibernate, session, struts2, annotations, mapping

In my case:

Rack and Slot are entities having custom ID Generators. I am using unidirectional one-to-one mapping. Dimension table will hold the data with a Autogenerated Custom ID as foreign key for multiple tables (Rack and Slot for example here). And my schema looks like this : Rack ------> Dimension <-----------Slot where Dimension will hold the data for Rack and Slot table with Generated ID.

Here the concern is that when i am saving the data like this:-

```
Rack rack = new Rack(params);
Dimension dim = new Dimension(params);
rack.setDimension(dim);
session.save(rack);
```

Data is being saved successfully with same Autogenerated ID in Rack and Dimension Tables.

But when I am saving the data for Slot table :

```
Slot Slot = new Slot(params);
Dimension dim = new Dimension(params);
slot.setDimension(dim);
session.save(slot);
```

it is showing error message as:-

attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property: rack

Can I pass the dynamic property name as "slot" when saving the data for Slot and Dimension and "rack" when saving the data for Rack and Dimension.

Rack.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tablename")
@GenericGenerator(name = "customseq", strategy = "CustomIdGenerator")
public class Rack {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "customseq")
  @Column(name = "uni_id")
  private String id;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Dimension dimension;
  // Getters and Setters
}
```

Slot.java

```
@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name = "slot_seq", strategy = "com.slot.SlotIdGenerator")
@Table(name = "\"slot_info\"")
public class Slot implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "slot_seq")
  @Column(name = "slot_id")
  private String slotid;
  @Column(name = "rack_id")
  private String rackid;
  @Column(name = "element_id")
  private String elementid;
  @Column(name = "sr_no")
  private int srno;   
  @JoinColumn(name = "systemid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Dimension dimension;
  // getters and setters
}
```

Dimension.java

```
public class Dimension implements Serializable{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "systemid")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "foreign", strategy = "foreign", parameters = {
  @Parameter(name = "property", value = "slot"),
  @Parameter(name = "property", value = "rack")})
  private String systemid;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dimension", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Rack rack;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dimension", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Slot slot;
  // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: What is the code for the `Slot`?

Comment: @RomanC
`
Sorry, i forgot to post, Here is Slot.java  

   @Entity
    @GenericGenerator(name = "slot_seq", strategy = "com.slot.SlotIdGenerator")
    @Table(name = "\"slot_info\"")
    public class Slot implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "slot_seq")
    @Column(name = "slot_id")
    private String slotid;
    @Column(name = "sr_no")
    private int srno;
    @JoinColumn(name = "systemid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Dimension dimension;
    // setters and getters

    }`

Comment: Don't post the code in comments, edit your question and add details.

Comment: @RomanC, thanks, check it out now..i have edited the question!

Comment: Your `Dimention` entity has a `rack` property, you should assign it an a value.

Comment: well.it works fine in case when i am saving data for Rack nd Dimension coz it'll get a foreign key from Rack entity since it (Dimension entity) has GenericGenerator property name value="rack" replacing value="slot"
  But when i am saving data for Slot and Dimension it will look up for the foreign key(or GenericGenerator will provide the key) :-
`
    @GenericGenerator(name = "foreign", strategy = "foreign", parameters = {
  @Parameter(name = "property", value = "slot"),
  @Parameter(name = "property", value = "rack")})
`
and again it is looking for foreign key in Rack entity instead of Slot